# Select error in Linq

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

When i tried the code

```
Actor[] act =
new Actor[]
{
  new Actor
  {
    Name = "Jacky",
    ID = "JZ01",
    FilmList =
    {
      new Film
      {
        Title = "Twin Brothers",
        Period = Convert.ToDateTime("01/Nov/1993")
      },
      new Film
      {
        Title = "Police Story",
        Period = Convert.ToDateTime("05/Aug/1989")
      }
    }
  },
  new Actor
  {
    Name = "Tom Cruise",
    ID = "JZ09",
    FilmList = 
    {
      new Film
      {
        Title = "Mission Impossible I",
        Period = Convert.ToDateTime("01/Jun/1998")
      },
      new Film 
      {
        Title = "Mission Impossible II",
        Period = Convert.ToDateTime("05/Aug/2001")
      }
    }
  }  
};

class Actor
{
    string name;
    string id;
    List<Film> flm=new List<Film>();

     public string Name
     {
       get { return name; }
       set { name = value; }
     }

     public string ID
     {
          get { return id; }
          set { id = value; }
     }

     public List<Film> FilmList
     {
        get { return flm; }
        set { flm = value; }
     }

   }

  class Film
  {
     string title;
     DateTime period;

     public string Title
     {
       get { return title; }
       set { title = value; }
     }

     public DateTime Period
     {
         get { return period; }
         set { period = value; }
     }
   }
```

...Main()
..

```
var sqry = from actr in Actor select actr;
```

I recieved "Could not find the implementation of the query pattern..Select not found".

May i know the reason which stops the execution?

Answer (score 1):

The `Actor` class doesn't implement `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, so you can't run a query on it (and anyway `Actor` is a type, not an instance of a type)...

Did you mean `from actr in act select actr` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a select directly over the `Actor` class since it does not implement `IEnumerable` nor `IQueryable`. You should instead query the `act` array.